# Sticky bottom bar not sticking in standalone for iPhone X

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, web-applications

I am building a web-based standalone application for iPhone X. In testing it on my phone's browser, the sticky bottom bar stays on the bottom. However, in standalone, there is a white gap between the bottom of the bar and the bottom of the screen, like this:

[There is a white gap between the bottom of the bar and the bottom of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxuc8.png)

The bar *should* stick to the bottom of the phone screen. It should look like this (ignore the buttons):

[The bar should stick to the bottom of the phone screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0olw6.png)

I cannot figure out why this is happening. [Click here for a demo.](http://incidentreport.x10host.com/doorbell-new/)

**As requested, here is the CSS for the bottom bar:**

```
.bottom-bar {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height:75pt;
    z-index:1;
    background:#008080;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.62);
}
```

Thank you all so much. :)

Comment: Are you loading on Safari or on a web view inside your own iOS application?

Comment: @pranay Sorry for late response. This is a standalone application by use of Add To Home Screen in Safari.

Comment: Can you show us the css styles for you the bottom bar?

Comment: @CoryKleiser Sorry about that. Got it now. Even with `body` and `html` at full width, I have to scroll up to get the bar to the bottom.

Comment: And this is only behaving like this on iPhone X?

Comment: @CoryKleiser Well, I found out that a `black-translucent` bar causes this. The white portion at the bottom is the height borrowed by the transparent top bar. Is there any way to regain full height?

Comment: Interesting. If you know the height or just experiment to find it you could try a negative value for bottom or margin-bottom.

Comment: But then of course you would have to add logic to only apply that style if the user agent was iPhone X

Comment: @CoryKleiser true, I would have to check user agent. I tried using negative bottom values, but that just makes it disappear into the white bottom area. Testing this on my iPad, there is the same problem, but there is less white space. If I scroll, I can fill the screen temporarily, but as soon as I let go, it goes back to filling only part of the screen.

Comment: On the iPad it’s going to be relatively hard to do because your trying to get rid of the browsers bottom control bar that lets the user navigate back and forth, share a page, etc. that will be near impossible because it’s part of the browser. It disappears on scroll down to give the user more screen space and reappears on scroll up. It might be the same deal on the iPhone X. The bottom bar may just be formatted different compared to the other iPhones and iPads. I think you’re gonna be stuck with this one.

Comment: @CoryKleiser Well, alright. It's not a control bar that I am talking about. I mean that when I make the top bar with the time and cell reception transparent, I get a small white gap at the bottom. Perhaps I am stuck with this one.